# What is the meaning of ^\d*(\:d+)?$. or ^\d*(\:d+)?$

Tags: regex

As the title suggests, what is the meaning of `^\d*(\:d+)?$` and what difference of `.` in the end means i.e. `^\d*(\:d+)?$.`

Comment: You seem to have written the same expression twice, and a different expression (twice) in the title.

Comment: Is the "." at the end of the second regex part of the regex, or is it the end of the sentence?  (Given that you ask specifically about '.' I assume it's part of the regex, but want to be certain)

Comment: You can evaluate your expression on <https://regex101.com>, it gives you explanation. You can also add some test cases.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It seems that it trims a dot at the end of title. So I put it at the end of first regex.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` at the end of `^\d*(:d+)?$.` is most likely the end of a sentence and most likely not part of the regex itself.

Why?: `$` is a symbol for the end of a line, so unless you are using regex to match multi-line strings (rare but possible) the `.` wouldn't match anything because nothing comes after the end of the string.

What does the regex mean?:

- `^` start of string
- `\d*` 0 or more digits
- `(:d+)?` possibility of a `:` followed by one or more `d` (prob a typo and they meant \d again)
- `$` end of string

this most likly matches patterns like:

- `:1` where `\d*` can have 0 or more entries
- `12` where `:` and stuff after `:` is optional
- 1234567890 where `\d*` can have multiple entries and `:` and numbers after `:` are optional
- `1:2` where you have atleast 1 of everything
- `1234567890:123` where you have many digits on either side of `:`

Comment: In PCRE when `m` is off `$` has the same behavior as `\Z` which matches the position at the end of input string or before the linebreak after the end of input string. In this case, with `s` flag set, `$.` will match (See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/LGIHYm/1)). But I agree that probably it is not part of the regex.

Comment: `unless you are using regex to match multi-line strings (rare but possible)` ... you can also force python to match multi-line strings ... people sometimes use this when trying to commune with ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡

Comment: `match multi-lines string` has different interpretations i.e. 1) to match multi-line strings so that `$` matches at the end of each line or 2) to match multi-line strings so that  `.` matches linebreaks. The former could be achieved by setting `m` (MULTILINE) flag (except in Ruby) and the latter with `s` (DOTALL) flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
. Dot Matches any character except linebreaks
```

Form detail information put your regex here: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

For such cases as your question, a wonderful solution is to find
a regex tester page, e.g. https://regex101.com/

Then:

- Copy your regex in the respective field (*REGEX EXPRESSION*).
- Hover the mouse over each part of the regex.
- You will see a description concerning the part under the cursor.

Take also a look at the right upper corner, with *EXPLANATION* heading.
It contains very detailed explanation of the regex.

And as far as your regex is concerned: `(\:d+)` looks a bit strange, because:

- The colon (`:`) does not require any `\` in front of them.
- Maybe the proper redaction should be `(:\d+)` i.e. a colon followed
  by a sequence of digits?

The regex modified as above would match e.g. source string like `789:456`.

For an example see https://regex101.com/r/kKz9oo/1